# Power BI Embed for customer is not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, azure-active-directory, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a sample of Power BI embed for customer on asp.netcore working in Visual Studio. I'm able to test this using swagger api docs. But this api application refuses to work once I build & deploy it to an IIS Server. it produces the error below:

One or more errors occurred. (Request to the endpoint timed out.)

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at AppOwnsData.Services.AadService.GetAccessToken() in line 48
at AppOwnsData.Services.PbiEmbedService.GetPowerBIClient() in line 33

Comment: What's that sample? Did you follow Microsoft's tutorial? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core

Comment: Yes, I used the .NetCore embed for customers sample using master user authentication following Microsoft's tutorial. It works perfectly in development environment. But it doesn't work when I build/ publish it with visual studio and deploy on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

My Power BI Embedded Application now works in it's production server. The challenge was caused by the firewall restriction Policy implemented by Our Cybersecurity Team. Once, the Team allowed the application to access the internet on the server, the embed for customer application worked.